# How to delete extra added "closed tags" in the malformed XML file with java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

There is a generated XML file which is malformed i.e., getting added unwanted closed tags (which are leading  to malformed XML file).I am successful in solving the this issue by deleting the extra added the closed tags with the help of shell commands in java file like below:

```
int NoofTags=Integer.parseInt(CommandExecution("grep -c \"</person>\" " + file + "").toString().trim());
if(NoofTags > 1)
{
        CommandExecution("sed -i \'/^<\\/person>$/d\' " + file + "");//Remove all </person> tags in the XML file
        CommandExecution("echo \'</person>\' "+ " >> " + file + "");//Adding </person> tag at end of the XMLfile
}
```

Here "file" is an XML file."person" is the root element.Issue here is multiple `</person>` closed tags are getting added in the middle of XML file randomly which are unwanted(which is leading to malformed XML). So I have deleted all the closed tags  at a time by using `sed` command and added one closed tag at the end of the file in-order to close the root element "person".Now the problem is solved.

But I could not solve this using Java XML parsing techniques.

Can any one help me in solving this issue with the help of java XML parsing techniques (eg: DOM parser) ?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better solved by fixing the process that creates the malformed XML file.

Comment: Could you share the Java code that have you written?

Comment: the java xml parser will tell you where the error is in your xml doc... you can probably use that info to help you fix the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When parsing XML in java you will find that the vast majority of API (all which I have come across) will throw an exception if the input is found not to be "well formed". This is because if the input is not "well formed" then technically it is not XML.

When parsing XML it is good practice to reject anything which is not well formed.

It is also good practice to solve the cause of a bug/problem, rather than fixing the symptom.

My suggestion is to fix the generation of your XML.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will implement as you suggested.But I have to to fix this issue as a temporary. Can you suggest me how to delete extra added closed tags with the help of java XML parsing techniques ?

Comment: I have used several APIs for parsing XML and all of them throw an exception if the structure is wrong, although you should find some clues in the exception to identify the location of your erroneous end tag, which will help you remove the correct one in your String. although this is not a nice solution, and may be just as difficult as fixing it properly.